# how to find from which sub-type was the result found in elasticsearch?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, uri

Hello all and thanks in advance,

I have data indexed on elasticsearch server in the following manner

```
{
    'main_index':{
        'type':[{
            'name':'john deo',
            'type':'accountant',
            'description':'john deo is a great person',
            'address':'somewhere in the world'
        },
        {
            'name':'calvin kalvin',
            'type':'designer',
            'description':'calvin kalvin is john deo's best friend',
            'address':'somewhere near'
        }]
    }
}
```

my query is when i search for `great person` it should also return me its `sub-type`, say `name or type or description or address`

eg.:

`http://localhost:9200/some-index/type?q=great person`

So along with the complete result it should also return its sub-type i.e.:`description`. i tried `highlighter` but of no use.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
GET /my_index/type/_search?q=great person
{
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {"name": {},"type": {},"description": {},"address": {}}
  }
}
```

Which gives you:

```
 "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.10848885,
        "_source": {
           "name": "john deo",
           "type": "accountant",
           "description": "john deo is a great person",
           "address": "somewhere in the world"
        },
        "highlight": {
           "description": [
              "john deo is a <em>great</em> <em>person</em>"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

If you put, also, "world" in the search query (so `q=great person world`) it gives you:

```
 "hits": [
     {
        "_index": "my_index",
        "_type": "type",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.13287117,
        "_source": {
           "name": "john deo",
           "type": "accountant",
           "description": "john deo is a great person",
           "address": "somewhere in the world"
        },
        "highlight": {
           "address": [
              "somewhere in the <em>world</em>"
           ],
           "description": [
              "john deo is a <em>great</em> <em>person</em>"
           ]
        }
     }
  ]
```

Comment: but how do i add highlight to my uri query string

Comment: Just using the query string? No, this is not supported in ES. You have to use a query like the one I posted in my answer. Something like `/my_index/type/_search?q=great person&highlight=whatever` is not supported.